# Using dynamic_cast for collision detection in a 2D environment

Tags: c++, c++11, collision-detection, variadic-templates

I'm developing a base for a 2D game. My general design is something like this:

```
class Entity:
    Every object class (like a wall, an enemy, floor etc.) derives
    from this class. Most of the functions are pure virtual. There is
    a hitbox as well.

class Scene:
    Contains pointers to Entity-objects. When an Entity-pointer is added,
    it will be given a Scene-pointer to its parent so it may access that.
```

Scene also has a collision-detecting function:

```cpp
getIntersections<T> (Entity *)
getIntersections<T...> (Entity *)
    (both return a std::vector<Entity *>)
```

This basically gets all `Entity *`s intersecting the parameter-`Entity *` (by checking the hitbox) and then tries to `dynamic_cast<T *>` them. All matching `Entity *`s (not the casted ones) are then returned. The variadic template is used for checking for more then one intersecting class.

My basic idea behind that was, if I had a `Player`-class (which represents the player obviously), and some other classes like `Enemy`, `Wall`, etc., it would be an easy task to check if a `Player`-object was colliding with one(or more) of these:

```cpp
// (inside Player::tick(); quick and dirty)
{
    if ( (this->parentScene->getIntersections<Wall>(this)).empty() )
        // player does not collide with a wall, just move.
    else
        // player does collide with a wall, do whatever.
}
```

However, I have got two questions on that:

1. Does my (general) design show up flaws for the need of `dynamic_cast<T *>` as replacement for `instanceof` (like there is in Java for example)
2. Is it a performant solution on the task? Since for every collision check, `Scene` basically loops through **every** `Entity *` it contains, checks if it collides with the given `Entity *` and finally casts it to check if it derives from another given class. If that is *not* performant, what changes were to make in my design to make it performant?

Comment: I would guess that the `dynamic_cast<>`s are not performant in your sense. However, the proof of the pudding is in the eating: just try and see!

Comment: I would define some object types as an enum. Then add a pure virtual function to your `Entity` class that returns the object's type. That way multiple object can be of the same type, for example if you want to define different types of walls. Also this works nice with inheritance (for example deriving a `LargeWall` and a `SmallWall` from Wall, and both return the object-type `COLLIDABLE_WALL`).

Comment: when do you treat `Entity` of different types uniformly in `Scene`?

Comment: @Marius Yeah thats a quite nice solution, although it would need `Entity` to define all types of derived classes (I kind of dislike doing so). Also, how would I handle different types of enemies, since these might do different amounts of damage for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the performance part it would be better to separate entities in separate vectors by primitive type. Not only you can specifically test a plane vs a sphere for example it eliminates the need to have dynamic_cast entirely ( -> extra speedup ). Also since you already separated the types in vectors you can just ignore the virtual functions and go for non virtual call providing additional performance improvement;
So your scene would look something like this:

```
class scene
{
    std::vector<PlaneEntity> m_planes;
    std::vector<CircleEntity> m_circles;
};
```

And regarding the design of this it is much easier to select the right algorithm when intersecting primities:
This is an example on how a basic collision checking would look based on this design:

```
void colide(const PlaneEntity & e)
{
    for each plane
        call plane vs plane collision
    for each circle
        call plane vs circle collision;
};
void colide(const CircleEntity & e)
{
    for each plane
        call plane vs circle collision;
    for each circle
        call circle vs circle collision;
};
```

So to answer your question:

1: it is not a rule weather to use or not dynamic_cast, it is known that not using it is better for performance.

2: The design described above is not performant at all. Also your design with dynamic cast is even slower. To improve this you need to look into accelerations structures (this is huge topic so i can't explaing everything here) to speed up collision detection. They basically reduce the number of collision check for each primitive giving a massive improvement in performance. Basic structures are KD-Tree, Quad-Trees, Spacial-Hash , Grid, etc. You can find lots of code for each just by googleing them.

Hope this helps,
Raxvan.